# Number of integers satisfying inequalities with logarithm: $2\lt \log_x45\lt3$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I am trying to solve the problem of finding the integers x satisfying the inequalities:
$2\lt \log_x45\lt3$

I realize this is a very basic question on logarithms and I have the key with the answers 4, 5, 6 and have confirmed this is correct using Wolfram Alpha but which steps should I take to reach that answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite this as $$2 < \ln(45)/\ln(x) < 3$$ and then $$2\ln(x) < \ln(45) < 3\ln(x)$$ since $\ln(x)$ must be positive. Then this becomes $$\ln(x^2) < \ln(45) < \ln(x^3)$$ and finally exponentiating turns this into the inequality: $$x^2 < 45 < x^3.$$ Now just plug in a few integers to figure out exactly which ones work.

Comment: $\sqrt[3]{45} \in (3,4)$ and $\sqrt{45}\in(6,7)$ give the answer without "trying".

Comment: Certainly. My approach changed this problem to a problem of polynomial inequalities. It did not involve "trying", it just used a basic property of logarithms.

Comment: I was just referring to the last sentence. No need to plug in there.